# Multiple RewriteRule in htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am very well aware that such type questions have already been asked many times but I think mine is a different one. I am a newbee to `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/index.php
RewriteRule (.*) localhost/index.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ leather-product.php?n=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^bagsgentssel1/([0-9]+)$ bagsgentssel1.php?h=$1 [L] 

# RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# RewriteRule ^bagsgentssel1/([0-9]+)$ bagsgentssel1.php?h=$1 [QSA,L]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ leather-product.php?n=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I run my code `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ leather-product.php?n=$1 [QSA,L]`, this works fine. But when I try to run the second rule `RewriteRule ^bagsgentssel1/([0-9]+)$ bagsgentssel1.php?h=$1 [L]`, this does not work. No error is shown here and in the chrome browser URL is shown as `http://localhost/bagsgentssel1/45`.

Interesting part is if I comment below code then the second `RewriteRule ^bagsgentssel1/([0-9]+)$ bagsgentssel1.php?h=$1 [L]` works fine.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ leather-product.php?n=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I am unable to find where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the directives in the wrong order. You need the more *specific* directives first.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ leather-product.php?n=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

Your first rule catches *everything* (with pattern `^(.*)$`), so your second rule is never actually reached. You need to either make the above `RewriteRule` *pattern* more specific (eg. only match numbers or something) so that it doesn't conflict with the second rule. Or reverse your two rules to have the second (more specific) rule first:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^bagsgentssel1/([0-9]+)$ bagsgentssel1.php?h=$1 [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ leather-product.php?n=$1 [QSA,L]
```

> Interesting part is if I comment below code then the second `RewriteRule ^bagsgentssel1/([0-9]+)$ bagsgentssel1.php?h=$1 [L]` works fine.

Exactly, you are removing the directive that conflicts / catches everything.

mod_rewrite directives are processed top to bottom. If a directive at the top of the file catches the request then all directives that follow could be skipped.

If you have no other directives then the above could be rewritten:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^bagsgentssel1/([0-9]+)$ bagsgentssel1.php?h=$1 [L] 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ leather-product.php?n=$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/index.php
> RewriteRule (.*) localhost/index.php [R=301,L]
> ```

I'm not sure what this is supposed to be doing, but it's not actually doing anything (the *condition* will never match). Although if it did, it looks like it would *break*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. Can you please suggest any book or reference guide from where i can learn more about RewriteRule/RewriteCond used in htaccess.

Comment: If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted (checkmark below the voting arrows on the left) to remove it from the unanswered question queue. Once you have 15+ rep then you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)

Comment: Although not everyones cup of tea, my go-to is the Apache Docs: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html) and [Apache Module mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) - very concise, but perhaps lacking in "depth". When undertsanding mod_rewrite you need to question every single character, unfortunately mod_rewrite directives are notoriously copy/pasted and missinformation spreads.